# id,name,price,ImageUrl not defined?

Tags: angular, typescript

```
export class Product{
    id:number;
    name: string;
    price:number;
    ImageUrl:string;
```

I get the following error

error TS2564: Property 'ImageUrl' has no initializer and is not definitely assigned in the constructor. ImageUrl:string;

Comment: Can you paste your constructor body?

Comment: It seems you are using it without initialising it. Either initialise it in constructor or while declaring it `ImageUrl = "";` (no need to explicitly define string type, it is implicitly string)

Answer (score 1):

You have two options there:

One is to start the attributes, like this:

```
export class Product {
    id:number = 0;
    name: string = '';
    price:number = 0;
    ImageUrl:string = '';
```

The other ( preferable ) is to mark them with the ! or ?, which tells the ts that these attributes are optional (?) or required (!)

```
export class Product {
    id!: number;
    name!: string;
    price!: number;
    ImageUrl?: string;
```

Take a better look in [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#optional-and-default-parameters)